# NodeJS crypto module doesn't work with http module

Tags: node.js, http, scrypt

I'm running a simple web server using NodeJS (to which I'm using the http module) and I am trying to create a username/password login system using the crypto module. Specifically, I'm using `crypto.scryptSync()` to hash the passwords. However, whenever I run these two together, such as in below:

```
const http = require('http');
const crypto = require('crypto');

console.log(crypto.scryptSync('password', 'salt', 64));
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'content-type': 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('ok');
});
server.listen(80);
```

I get an error stating that `TypeError: crypto.scryptSync is not a function` and I don't know why.
Is there something incorrect in the way that I import the modules or are they just incompatible?
I'm running NodeJS v12.18.3, but the same still happens on the latest version.

Comment: This runs fine on my machine (Node v12.16.2) are you sure this code reproduces the issue? It seems like you are shadowing the `crypto` variable with a different variable in your request handler.

Comment: Also, confirm the output of this in your node script: "console.log(process.version)". Not uncommon to have multiple versions of node installed, and attempting to the run the script with the wrong version.

Comment: @user2263572 that may be the problem, I ran it and got `v8.10.0'. Does that version of node not support `crypto.scryptSync()`? And how do I change it to a different version?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue.  I believe it's first supported in 10+.  In your command line type "which node".  That will be the path to the install you're currently using (assuming you are executing your script like  "node yourscript.js").  Download the latest version of nodejs, and update your path to point to that new version.  When "which node" returns the path to the newer version, you will be all set.  google away.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `crypto.scryptSync()` was released in NodeJS v10.5.0. Since I was running my script as `sudo`, an older version of NodeJS was being used, causing the error.